# Joi, validate different array schemas based on array length

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, joi

I have been running into an issue with Joi that I've struggled to solve and I've used a ton of different syntax to try and solve it.

Basically we have two schemas below. Say there are 5 options in a dropdown. If the array only has one item only arraySchemaOne is required and if it has more than one item then both Schema one and two are required.

```
const arraySchemaOne = Joi.object({
    dropdown: Joi.string().valid('Option 1')
}).required();

const arraySchemaTwo = Joi.object({
    dropdown: Joi.string().valid('Option 2')
}).required();

this.validationPattern = Joi.object().pattern(/\w/, Joi.object(
    {
          rows: Joi.ref('rows.length >= 2')
          ?
          Joi.array().items([arraySchemaOne, arraySchemaTwo])
          :
          Joi.array().items([arraySchemaOne])
    }
));
```

If anyone has any syntax that could help in solving this issue it would be great. I've tried many things the past few days and have been unable to solve this issue.

Comment: Hi @KatherineGG28is there a reason you're using Joi for frontend? Joi is not very good for browser validation, Yup is a browser alternative that has a similar API. Also, could you please explain what you're trying to achieve with this in terms of data and not schemas?

Comment: Joi was introduced by another engineer and in every other case it's worked great for our data schemas. Basically I have an array of objects. When only one item is in the array the value of dropdown must be option 1, when two items are in the value of one must be option 1 and the value of the other must be option 2. When there are more than two items say 5 items, one of them must have a value with option 1 and another must have option 1 but the other 3 can be anything.

Answer (score 0):

@katherineGG28 you might wanna look into the following documentation, the joi API exposes a `when` method in which you can pass the ref you already have as a first parameter and then populate the options with your alternative schemas. On a side note, if another engineer introduced the library, you should at least check out the README file on the repo which clearly states this lib was not designed with browsers in mind.

https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v14.3.1/API.md#anywhencondition-options

Comment: yeah, I guess that happens when you don't get to the bottom of the page, the implementation you want is covered by the provided api though.
 https://github.com/hapijs/joi#browsers

Comment: I don't think switching to Yup is going to lead to automatically solving this case. The issue is doesn't seem to be a simple way to validate an array of objects based on if the array length is a certain number. This wasn't a question of which validation api to use, it was a question of how to deal with a certain case of validation.